# How to clean csv by another csv while in a 'for' loop?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, csv

I'm not a linux expert, and usually in this situation PHP would be much more suitable... But due to the circumstances it occurred that I wrote it in Bash :)

I have the following .sh which runs over all .csv files in the current folder and execute a bunch of commands.
The goal:   Cleaning email lists in .csv files (not actually .csv but just a .txt file in practice).

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.csv" ); do
echo "====================================================" >> db_purge_log.txt
echo "$file" >> db_purge_log.txt
echo "----------------------------------------------------" >> db_purge_log.txt
echo "Contacts BEFORE purge:" >> db_purge_log.txt
wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1 >> db_purge_log.txt
echo " " >> db_purge_log.txt
cat $file | egrep -v "xxx|yyy|zzz" | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file
mv tmp_file $file ;
echo "Contacts AFTER purge:" >> db_purge_log.txt
wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1 >> db_purge_log.txt
done
```

Now the trouble is:

I want to add a command, somewhere in the middle of this loop, to use another .csv file as suppression list, meaning - every line found as perfect match in that suppression list - delete from `$file`.

At this point my brain is stuck and I can't think of a solution. To be honest, I didn't manage using `sort` or `grep` on 2 different files and export to a 3rd file without completely eliminating the duplicated lines cross both files, so I end up with much less data.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Clean up

Before adding functionality to the script, the existing script needs to be cleaned up — a lot.

#### I/O Redirection — Don't Repeat Yourself

When I see wall-to-wall I/O redirections like that, I want to cry — that isn't how you do it!  You have three options to avoid all that:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.csv" )
do
    echo "===================================================="
    echo "$file"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Contacts BEFORE purge:"
    wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1
    echo " "
    cat $file | egrep -v "xxx|yyy|zzz" | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file
    mv tmp_file $file ;
    echo "Contacts AFTER purge:"
    wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1
done  >> db_purge_log.txt
```

Or:

```
{
for file in $(find . -name "*.csv" )
do
    echo "===================================================="
    echo "$file"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Contacts BEFORE purge:"
    wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1
    echo " "
    cat $file | egrep -v "xxx|yyy|zzz" | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file
    mv tmp_file $file ;
    echo "Contacts AFTER purge:"
    wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1
done
}  >> db_purge_log.txt
```

Or even:

```
exec >>db_purge_log.txt   # By default, standard output will go to db_purge_log.txt
for file in $(find . -name "*.csv" )
do
    echo "===================================================="
    echo "$file"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Contacts BEFORE purge:"
    wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1
    echo " "
    cat $file | egrep -v "xxx|yyy|zzz" | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file
    mv tmp_file $file ;
    echo "Contacts AFTER purge:"
    wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1
done
```

The first form is adequate for this script which has a single loop in it to provide I/O redirection to.  The second form, using `{` and `}` would handle more general sequences of commands.  The third form, using `exec`, is 'permanent'; you can't recover the original standard output, whereas with the `{` ... `}` form you can have different sections of the script writing to different places.

One other advantage of all these variations is that you can trivially send errors to the same place that you're sending standard output if that's what you desire.  For example:

```
exec >>db_purge_log.txt 2>&1
```

#### Other issues

- Suppressing file name from `wc` — instead of:

  ```
  wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1
  ```

  use:

  ```
  wc -l < $file
  ```
- [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) — Useless use of `cat` — instead of:

  ```
  cat $file | egrep -v "xxx|yyy|zzz" | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file
  ```

  use:

  ```
  egrep -v "xxx|yyy|zzz" $file | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file
  ```
- UUOU — Useless use of `uniq`

  It is not at all clear why you need `uniq` and `sort -u`; in context, `sort -u` is sufficient, so:

  ```
  egrep -v "xxx|yyy|zzz" $file | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | sort -u  > tmp_file
  ```
- UUOG — Useless use of `grep`

  `egrep` is equivalent to `grep -E` and both are capable of handling multiple regular expressions, and the second will match what is matched by the expression in the parentheses 3 or more times (we really only need to match three times), so in fact the second expression will do the job of the first.  And the `[0-z]` match is dubious.  It probably matches sundry punctuation characters as well as the upper and lower case digits, but you're already doing a case-insensitive search because of the `-i`, so we can regularize all that to:

  ```
  grep -Eiv '([0-9a-z]){3}' $file | sort -u > tmp_file
  ```
- File names with spaces

  The code is not going to handle file names with spaces, tabs or newlines because of the `for file in $(find ...)` notation.  It probably isn't necessary to deal with that now — be aware of the issue.

#### Final clean up

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.csv" )
do
    echo "===================================================="
    echo "$file"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Contacts BEFORE purge:"
    wc -l < $file
    echo " "
    grep -Evi '([0-9a-z]){3}' | sort -u  > tmp_file
    mv tmp_file $file
    echo "Contacts AFTER purge:"
    wc -l <$file
done >> db_purge_log.txt
```

### Add the extra functionality

> I want to add a command, somewhere in the middle of this loop, to use another `.csv` file as suppression list — meaning that every line found as perfect match in that suppression list should be deleted from `$file`.

Since we're already sorting the input files (`$file`), we can sort the suppression file (call it `suppfile='suppressions.txt'`too if it is not already sorted.  Given that, we then use `comm` to eliminate the lines that appear in both `$file` and `$suppfile`.  We're interested in the lines that only appear in `$file` (or, as will be the case here, in the edited and sorted version of the file), so we want to suppress the common entries and the entries from `$suppfile` that do not appear in `$file`.  The `comm -23 - "$suppfile"` command reads the edited, sorted file from standard input `-` and leaves out the entries from `"$suppfile"`

```
suppfile='suppressions.txt'   # Must be in sorted order

for file in $(find . -name "*.csv" )
do
    echo "===================================================="
    echo "$file"
    echo "----------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Contacts BEFORE purge:"
    wc -l < "$file"
    echo " "
    grep -Evi '([0-9a-z]){3}' | sort -u | comm -23 - "$suppfile" > tmp_file
    mv tmp_file "$file"
    echo "Contacts AFTER purge:"
    wc -l < "$file"
done >> db_purge_log.txt
```

If the suppression file is not in sorted order, simply sort it into a temporary file.  Beware of using the `.csv` suffix on the suppression file in the current directory; it will catch the file and empty it because every line in the suppression file matches a line in the suppression file, which is not helpful for any files processed after the suppression file.

---

Oops — I over-simplified the `grep` regex.  It should (probably) be:

```
grep -Evi '([0-9a-z])\1{2}' $file
```

The difference is considerable.  My original rewrite will look for any three adjacent digits or letters (e.g. `123` or `abz`); the revision (actually very similar to one of the original commands) looks for a character from `[0-9A-Za-z]` followed by two occurrences of the same character (e.g. `111` or `aaa`, but not `123` or `abz`).

If perchance the alternatives `xxx|yyy|zzz` were really not 3 repeated characters, you might need two invocations of `grep` in sequence.

Comment: I'm completely speechless!

Comment: As long as it is because you're enthralled and not because you're appalled, speechlessness is OK :D

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, assuming a recent 'nix, `grep` should do most of the trick for you.  The command, `grep -vf filterfile input.csv` will output the lines in input.csv that do NOT match any regular expression found in filterfile.

A couple of other comments ... `uniq` needs the input sorted in order to remove dups, so you might want the `sort` before it in the pipe (unless your input data is sorted).

Or if the input is sorted to start with, `grep -u` will omit duplicates.

Small suggestion -- you might add a `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in order to ensure that the script is run by bash rather than the user's login shell (it might not be bash).
HTH.
b